# Modern UI : How i can select TAB from Moderntab by code

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, modern-ui

I have a ModernTab control, to which I'm dynamically adding a Link:

```
var link = new FirstFloor.ModernUI.Presentation.Link { DisplayName = "Otra Ventana", Source = new Uri("/pages/operations/confirm.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute) };

mtabs.Links.Add(link);
```

i want to programmatically go to or select this last TabPage , i tried this code :

```
   //  var frame = FirstFloor.ModernUI.Windows.Navigation.NavigationHelper.FindFrame(null, this);

     //   if (frame != null)
      //      frame.Source = new Uri("/pages/operations/confirm.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
```

but its only navigate to the page without moderntab !!

pleaze any help guys ?

Answer (score 1):

To select a link, use the existing `SelectedSouce` property in the `ModernTab` class:

```
mtabs.SelectedSource = new Uri("pages/operations/confirm.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
```